Por qué no puedo pasar el objeto user a otra pagina(next.js)?
Estoy tratando de asignar roles de usuario pero me estoy dando cuenta que en la pagina dashboard(usuario), esta apareciendo JSON no definidos, esto es solo si uso correo y contraseña, usando google solo aparece el nombre y el correo
Este es solo usando correo y contraseña para ingresar:
{ name: undefined, email: undefined, image: undefined }

pero en mi archivo route.ts si esta apareciendo todo el objeto del usuario, su nombre, apellido, correo, contraseña y el rol(role esta asi escrito en el codigo) despues de hacer su consulta a la base de datos, ahorita solo requiero que en las paginas aparezca la información del usuario o solo el rol, les paso los códigos que creo son parte del problema o ayudan a su resolución.
route.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connectDB } from "@/libs/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/usuarios";
import { GoogleProfile } from 'next-auth/providers/google';


const handler = NextAuth ({   //const handler = NextAuth({ -> lo que estaba antes
    providers: [ GoogleProvider ({
        profile(profile:GoogleProfile){
            return{
                ...profile,
                role: "usuario",
                id: profile.sub,
            }
        },
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,

        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
              email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
              password: { label: "Password", type: "text" },
            },
            
            async authorize(credentials: any) { //credentials: any

            {
              await connectDB();
              try {
                
                const user = await User.findOne({ correo: credentials.email });
                if (user && user.contrasena === credentials.password) {
                    // La contraseña coincide, puedes devolver el usuario
                    //console.log(user);
                    return user;
                } else {
                    // La contraseña no coincide
                    return null;
                }
              } catch (err: any) {
                throw new Error(err);
              }}  
            },
          })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        
        async signIn({user, account}) {
            if (account?.provider === 'credentials') {
                console.log(user);
                return true;
            }
            if (account && account.provider === 'google') {
                const {name, email} = user;
                try {
                    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios', { //http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            nombre: name,
                            correo: email,
                            role:  "usuario",
                        }),
                    });
                    if (res.ok) {
                        console.log(user)
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
});
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}; 

/dashboardU (la pagina en la que se envia despues de iniciar sesión)
import {useSession} from  'next-auth/react';
import { Footer} from "@/components"; {/*{ Footer, NavbarSignOut } */}
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import Image from 'next/image';
import NavbarUsuario from "@/components/NavbarUsuario";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";



  
const Dashboard = async () => { 
   const session = await getServerSession();
   console.log(session?.user) //aqui es donde se da el objeto indefinido
  
    if (!session) {
      redirect("/signin");
    }   
    
    return (
        <>
            <NavbarUsuario></NavbarUsuario>
            <main className="flex justify-center items-center w-full flex-1 main">

Voy a incluir tambien /signin, por si caso
"use client"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from 'next/image';
import CustomButton from '@/components/CustomButton';
import {signIn, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import { Navbar2 } from "@/components";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import CustomAlert from '@/components/CustomAlert';

export default function Form(){
    // const session = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState(""); // Mensaje de alerta
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
        router.replace("/dashboardU");
        }
    }, [sessionStatus, router]);

    const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target[0].value;
        const password = e.target[1].value;

        const res = await signIn('credentials', {
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false,
        });

        if (res?.error) {
            setAlertMessage("Contraseña y/o correo eléctronico incorrecto");
            setIsVisible(true);
            if (res?.url) router.replace("/dashboardU");
        }
    };

    if (sessionStatus === "loading") {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }

    return(
        <>
        <Navbar2 />

        <main className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full flex-1 bg-[#F5FFFC]">
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div className="flex max-w-3xl yellowContainer"> {/*div principal */}
                {/*Sección de iniciar sesión*/}
                <div className="logoContainer"> 
                    <Image
                        src="/atomo.png"
                        alt="atomo"
                        width={80}
                        height={48}
                        className="object-contain mx-auto logoSignIn" 
                    />
                    <div className="divYellowContainer"><h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center titleSignIn">Iniciar Sesión</h1><br />
                        <div className="flex flex-col w-full pl-4">
                            <form className="flex flex-col items-center w-full" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>                                 
                                <input type="email" className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Correo"/>
                                <br />
                                <input type="password" className="bg-white rounded-lg outline-none text-base h-12 pl-2 w-3/4 input" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
                            
                                <CustomButton
                                    btnType="submit"
                                    title="Iniciar Sesión"
                                    containerStyles="text-white rounded-full bg-[#FC83A1] hover:bg-[#E55E7F] font-medium mt-10 textButton"
                                />
                            </form><br />
                            <div className="flex justify-between">
                                <p className="text-black text-[17px] font-medium prSignIn">¿No tienes cuenta? <Link href="/signup" className="text-[#E55E7F]">Regístrate</Link></p>
                                <p className="text-black text-[17px] font-medium prSignIn"><Link href="" className="text-[#E55E7F]">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</Link></p>
                            </div>
                            {/* Renderizar alerta */}
                            {isVisible && (
                                <CustomAlert
                                    status="warning"
                                    variant="subtle"
                                    title="Error"
                                    description={alertMessage}
                                    setIsVisible={setIsVisible}
                                />
                            )}                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-nowrap items-center justify-center">
                            <div className="border-2 border-[#FC83A1] inline-block mb-2 pinkLine"></div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <p className="text-black text-[15px] font-bold">O</p>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div className="border-2 border-[#FC83A1] inline-block mb-2 pinkLine"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="flex justify-center my-2">&nbsp;
                        <button onClick={() => signIn('google', {callbackUrl: '/dashboardU' })} /**/className="flex items-center justify-center w-[299px] h-[59px] 
                        border-2 border-[#FFFFFF] bg-[#FFFFFF] rounded px-2 py-2 font-light text-center"> <Image
                        src="/buscar.png"
                        alt="mental"
                        width={40}
                        height={40}
                        className="mr-2 googleLogo" 
                        />Continuar con Google</button> {/*'google', { callbackUrl: '/dashboard' }*/ }
                        </div> <br /> 
                        <br />
                </div>
            </div> <br />
        </main>
        </>
    )
}

